# SQL - Populate temp table with date intervals with minimum impact on performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, date, stored-procedures, temp-tables

Inside a stored procedure, I need to populate my temp table with 7-day date intervals, between some @StartDate and @EndDate, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #DateIntervals (
    PeriodStartDate date,
    PeriodEndDate date
)

DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '1/1/2017';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '1/1/2018';

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #DateIntervals (PeriodStartDate, PeriodEndDate)
    SELECT @StartDate, DATEADD(day, 6, @StartDate)

    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 7, @StartDate)
END
```

It works fine, but it takes me **1483 milliseconds** to execute. If I then join this table with more data it will take even more time to execute. I need to somehow reduce this time to improve overall performance of the SP.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Can you create a `dates` table and pre-populate it with all 7-day spans for years and years? Then you simply `JOIN` to that table when needed? Indexing would help your performance, too.

Comment: There are better ways but that is incredibly slow to insert 53 rows.  For me it takes 13ms https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCLd8.png

Comment: Possibly something was wrong with my SQL Server. I have reloaded the app at it began to work much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single statement as below

```
   WITH 
    E1(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    )                                       -- 1*10^1 or 10 rows
    , E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)   -- 1*10^2 or 100 rows
    , Nums(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) FROM E2 a, E2 b)   -- 1*10^4 or 10,000 rows
    INSERT INTO #DateIntervals
                (PeriodStartDate,
                 PeriodEndDate)
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, N * 7 - 7, @StartDate),
           DATEADD(DAY, N * 7 - 1, @StartDate)
    FROM   Nums
    WHERE  N <= CEILING(DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 7.0);
```

This should be faster than 53 individual statements/transactions but 1.5 seconds sounds astonishingly slow for that against a temp table.